# Create runtime menu with VCL themes active = Error

Tags: delphi, toolbar, vcl-styles

Good night people.

When creating the Runtime Menu, I am facing the following problem when I have an active VCL theme.

WITHOUT ACTIVATING THE THEME:
[Image without theme enabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwpHv.png)

ACTIVATING THE THEME:
[Image with theme enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H6VO.png)

When making numerous attempts I noticed that this error occurs only when the menus are created dynamically.

Below is the source code ...

*

```
unit 
UFormPrincipal;
interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Actions,
  Vcl.ActnList, Vcl.Menus, System.ImageList, Vcl.ImgList, cxImageList,
  cxGraphics, UdmLista, Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.ToolWin;
type
  TFormPrincipal = class(TForm)
    btnAplicar: TButton;
    btnCarregarTema: TButton;
    btnCriarMenus: TButton;
    pgnModulos: TPageControl;
    ToolBarOne: TToolBar;
    procedure btnAplicarClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnCarregarTemaClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnCriarMenusClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FModuloLista: TdmLista;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
var
  FormPrincipal: TFormPrincipal;
implementation
Uses
  Vcl.Styles,
  Vcl.Themes;
{$R *.dfm}
procedure TFormPrincipal.btnAplicarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if btnAplicar.Caption = 'Aplicar CARBON' then begin
    btnAplicar.Caption := 'Aplicar WINDOWS';
    TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Carbon');
  end else begin
    btnAplicar.Caption := 'Aplicar CARBON';
    TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Windows');
  end;
end;
procedure TFormPrincipal.btnCarregarTemaClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TStyleManager.LoadFromFile('C:\Users\Jozimar\Desktop\TST\Tema\Carbon.vsf');
end;

procedure TFormPrincipal.btnCriarMenusClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  lMenu: TMainMenu;
  lItem: TMenuItem;
  lIndex: iNTEGER;
  TabSheet: TTabSheet;
begin
  TabSheet := TTabSheet.Create(pgnModulos);
  TabSheet.PageControl := pgnModulos;
  TabSheet.Caption := '  - Menu - ';
  ToolBarOne.Parent := TabSheet;
  lMenu := TMainMenu.Create(ToolBarOne);
  lMenu.Images := FModuloLista.ImageList1;
  lItem := TMenuItem.Create(lMenu);
  lItem.Caption := '    -- SubMenu --   ';
  lMenu.Items.Add(lItem);
  for lIndex := 0 to FModuloLista.ActionList1.ActionCount-1 do begin
    lItem := TMenuItem.Create(lMenu);
    lItem.Action := FModuloLista.ActionList1[lIndex];
    lMenu.Items[0].Add(lItem);
  end;
  ToolBarOne.Menu := lMenu;
end;
procedure TFormPrincipal.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FModuloLista := TdmLista.Create(Self);
end;
end.*

-------------------------------
*unit UdmLista;
interface
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.ImageList, Vcl.ImgList, Vcl.Controls,
  cxImageList, cxGraphics, System.Actions, Vcl.ActnList, Vcl.Menus;
type
  TdmLista = class(TDataModule)
    ActionList1: TActionList;
    Action1: TAction;
    Action2: TAction;
    Action3: TAction;
    Action4: TAction;
    ImageList1: TImageList;
    MainMenuOne: TMainMenu;
    Novidades1: TMenuItem;
    Action11: TMenuItem;
    Action21: TMenuItem;
    Action31: TMenuItem;
    Action41: TMenuItem;
    procedure Action1Execute(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Action2Execute(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Action3Execute(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Action4Execute(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
var
  dmLista: TdmLista;
implementation
Uses
  Vcl.Dialogs;
{%CLASSGROUP 'Vcl.Controls.TControl'}
{$R *.dfm}
procedure TdmLista.Action1Execute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('1111');
end;
procedure TdmLista.Action2Execute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('2222');
end;
procedure TdmLista.Action3Execute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('3333');
end;
procedure TdmLista.Action4Execute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('4444');
end;
end.*
```

- 

```
object FormPrincipal: TFormPrincipal
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Principal'
  ClientHeight = 428
  ClientWidth = 773
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object btnAplicar: TButton
    Left = 296
    Top = 273
    Width = 241
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Aplicar CARBON'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = btnAplicarClick
  end
  object btnCarregarTema: TButton
    Left = 177
    Top = 273
    Width = 113
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Carregar Tema'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = btnCarregarTemaClick
  end
  object btnCriarMenus: TButton
    Left = 96
    Top = 273
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Criar MENU'
    TabOrder = 2
    OnClick = btnCriarMenusClick
  end
  object pgnModulos: TPageControl
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 773
    Height = 97
    Align = alTop
    TabOrder = 3
  end
  object ToolBarOne: TToolBar
    Left = 0
    Top = 97
    Width = 773
    Height = 29
    Caption = 'ToolBarOne'
    TabOrder = 4
    Transparent = False
    StyleElements = []
    Wrapable = False
  end
end
```

- 

```
*object dmLista: TdmLista
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Height = 240
  Width = 442
  object ActionList1: TActionList
    Images = ImageList1
    Left = 248
    Top = 72
    object Action1: TAction
      Category = 'Dados Unidos'
      Caption = 'Action1'
      ImageIndex = 0
      OnExecute = Action1Execute
    end
    object Action2: TAction
      Category = 'Dados Unidos'
      Caption = 'Action2'
      ImageIndex = 1
      OnExecute = Action2Execute
    end
    object Action3: TAction
      Category = 'Dados Unidos'
      Caption = 'Action3'
      ImageIndex = 2
      OnExecute = Action3Execute
    end
    object Action4: TAction
      Category = 'Dados Unidos'
      Caption = 'Action4'
      ImageIndex = 3
      OnExecute = Action4Execute
    end
  end
  object ImageList1: TImageList
    Left = 176
    Top = 72
    Bitmap = {
      494C010104000800040010001000FFFFFFFFFF10FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF424D3600
      0000000000003600000028000000400000002000000001002000000000000020
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000010102021C1C384520225E791C2265801F2767801C1F607D23244D600B0B
      1216000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00000000000005070B0E5E84BCEA5077B0FF315187FF1A3A65FE02080E2E0000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00000000000000000000000000000000010103050E170102070B000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010
      1B204546A8D64659D8FF7294F5FF83A8FFFF82A7FEFF7B9FFAFF556EE2FF3D43
      BAEB1F1F35400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00000000000000000000000000005581B8FF325488FF1A3A65FF030B14440000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00000000000000000000000000000407151F15265E8B0C132637000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001E1E39463E48
      B8E05C78EFFF6989F8FF617EF1FF566DE6FF5368E2FF5D78EDFF6989F8FF6381
      F4FF4858D7FC282A657F00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000426693D334588CFF1A3A65FF030A133D0000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000010103050C111B2D7EA53551CEFA1C2C668B0A1124340102
      0508000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000B1F0E4118411F8A000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000E0E171C3337BEF9536B
      F0FF556EF2FF4458E2FF2F2FB1F631315B6F2525414E3F3F8BB2343BC5FC5069
      EEFF5670F4FF4250D6FC1B1B2E37000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00000000000000000000000000002E486897365D90FF1A3861F50716287B0815
      267003090F2B0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000101060A172215237EBA405FECFF5578FFFF314AC2EF20325F800E17
      2F43010104070000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000409A5BFF2F803BFF000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002729718E4051E8FF5D75
      F2FF576EF1FF4356ECFF3942D1FA1F20536B00000000000000001515252D3136
      97BC4357EAFF4458ECFF353AB9EC0C0C14180000000000000000000000000000
      00000000000008101B3C1629469E42699CF3385F93FF244473FF2B4C7FFF3151
      86FF35558BFE2336579200000000000000000000000000000000000000000406
      0E150E17416021359CCA3C5CEAFF4768F9FF5174F8FF587CF5FF3852C9F32032
      7CAA1622435C080D1C280101020400000000000000000000000000000000091D
      0B403E9D5EFF70D1A3FF2F803BFF000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003A3FBAE03A49EEFF3E4D
      DFFF556BE6FF4556EFFF3A4AEDFF2D34D0FE2B2B4D5D00000000000000001515
      252D2C31C5FC3A4AECFF2D37D9FF23234D600000000000000000000000000000
      000018284278385991FC3D5E99FF4C75AFFF386295FF243D64C219253B551821
      354B344975A15374B9F9080B111700000000000000000000000002030A10131F
      6DA02B44D2FF4162F2FF3C5BF3FF3856F1FF3A58F1FF4A6CF4FF5C80F6FF4565
      E3FF1B2E9DDF1A2A597E0910273B010104060000000000000000000000003B9C
      5BFF6DD4A6FF77D6ABFF2F803BFF358543FF3B8A4BFF409053FF46955AFF4C9A
      61FF509E67FF55A16CFF58A471FF00000000000000002E35D8FC2E39EBFF3035
      BBE12C2E82A23B48E1FF303AEAFF2C36E8FF282DD3FE21235A6E000000000000
      0000404191B22C35E4FF2D37EAFF1719647D0000000000000000000000002635
      54745173B7FF46629DD9243351713C5C89C5386094FF1120367C000000000000
      000000000000384E7BA22533506A01010202000000000304162316258FC5304B
      DDFF3C5BEEFF3754ECFF304CEBFF2E49EBFF2E48EBFF324DECFF3E5EECFF5072
      F1FF4F71EAFF2C43BCEC14226698060B1F3000000000071C08403A9D5CFF63D0
      9EFF6DD4A6FF77D6ABFF74D3A7FF7FD6ADFF88D7B2FF93D9B8FF9CDBBDFFA5DD
      C2FFADDFC6FF9BCFB3FF58A471FF00000000000000002329DEFF242AE7FF272A
      8DA7000000002D3190AE272FE2FF242BE7FF242AE8FF262CD8FE2D2F535F0000
      00002627444E252BDEFF252AE8FF11146A800000000000000000000000004C69
      A6DB4C6AA7DD090C131900000000263C5782375F92FF0E1C306E000000000000
      0000644A30989E7147FF95673DFF724C2BCC000000000E17709F2A43E4FF2F49
      E4FF2C45E4FF2740E4FF273FE4FF273FE4FF273FE4FF273FE4FF273FE4FF304B
      E6FF4667E9FF5072ECFF2237C4FF0910446E00000000389B5AFF5ED09DFF65D2
      A1FF6DD4A6FF77D6ABFF80D9B1FF8CDCB8FF96DEBEFFA1E1C5FFABE4CBFFB5E7
      D1FFBEE9D6FFA4D4BBFF58A471FF00000000000000001F24E0FF1C1FE6FF2B30
      9EB5000000000C0C15182C3194AD2127E1FE1C1FE6FF1C1FE4FF2429DAFE2124
      5D6A3437636F2025E1FF1B1FE7FF11156D80000000000506090C192235464D6A
      A8DE0D111B24000000000000000016213454365D90FF0F1C306D000000000000
      0000B3895CFFE2BB89FFD4A568FFB07E48FF00011E421B2CB4E92C45E1FF2439
      DEFF2136DDFF2136DDFF2136DDFF2136DDFF2136DDFF2136DDFF2136DDFF2236
      DDFF263BDDFF405FE4FF3C5BE2FF0E1771A6000000003C7346C08BE0B9FF65D2
      A1FF6DD4A6FF77D6ABFF80D9B1FF8CDCB8FF96DEBEFFA1E1C5FFABE4CBFFB5E7
      D1FFBEE9D6FFA4D4BBFF58A471FF00000000000000002C32DDF91A1AE5FF3137
      D3ED0000000000000000000000002E3599AE171BE1FF1617E2FF1617E4FF272D
      DEFC3D48D7F61719E3FF171AE4FF1F246B7900000000835F3DCC9B6D43FF9364
      3BFF5539229D000000000000000001010203315086FD11213880000000000000
      0000BD9466FFF2D7B4FFE6C295FFBE9363FF02034B7D2339C9FE4264DFFF253C
      D9FF1A2CD6FF1B2DD6FF1E30D7FF2338D8FF263DD9FF2237D8FF1D2FD6FF1A2C
      D6FF1A2BD6FF2A43DAFF3A58DFFF101B7FB500000000000000001B6F22FF8BDF
      B9FF6DD4A6FF77D6ABFF80D9B1FF8CDCB8FF94DDBDFF99DFC0FF99DEC0FF95DC
      BCFF8CD8B6FF85C9A7FF58A471FF00000000000000002C33B1C5262AE7FF1F23
      E3FF3B4296A204040707000000000C0D161830389DAF1C22E3FF1414E2FF1516
      E2FF181CE2FF1B1EE4FF212BE4FF1E21404500000000CDA679FFDDB37EFFD09E
      5EFF95663CFF0000000000000000000000000F182749142945A6000000000000
      00009D7D58CCDEBF9AFFD6B38AFFAB8760E601013D61273CC0F7698DE8FF314A
      D9FF1422D2FF1624D2FF263DD5FF4363DEFF5E81E4FF5072E1FF314BD8FF1929
      D3FF1320D2FF1F33D4FF2A42D7FF0B1271A40000000000000000000000003974
      47C083DDB4FF77D6ABFF2F803BFF1A42217E1D44257E2047297E234A2D7E264C
      307E284E337E2A50367F2C52398000000000000000002A316C731E26E6FF2F38
      E8FF161AE4FF3B4498A2000000000000000000000000323B95A0171BE5FF1414
      E2FF171AE4FF2E38E8FF4D58CBD90404060700000000DAB992FFEED1AAFFE1BB
      8AFF9F7247FF00000000000000007C5A3AC09D6F45FF96673DFF8C5D35FA2B1C
      104F000000000000000000000000000000000000121D1B2AA0D78DAEEFFF5E81
      E2FF273FD3FF1E31D1FF263ED3FF3E5DC7F66586BEE5A5C2F2FF7498E8FF3C5A
      D8FF2237D1FF1522CEFF1625CBFF0407486E0000000000000000000000000000
      000024762DFF84DDB4FF2F803BFF000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008080E0E3D49B8C33643
      ECFF4554EBFF2D37E9FF353EDCED2C33A9B6262E9CA72F38D0E11C23E7FF2F39
      E8FF404FECFF3946CFDE0F101B1C0000000000000000BF9F7BE6DCBC95FFD2AE
      84FF876442CC0000000000000000CAA375FEDCB37DFFD2A163FFC7914AFF4831
      1D7F00000000000000000000000000000000000000000609527A4B68D3FF96B5
      F0FF7094E6FF314CD4FF1624C7FF070B5F8E040615274D64B9E391B1EDFF84A7
      EBFF486ADBFF1522C9FF080C99E10101111F0000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000367648C02F803BFF000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003E4A
      B9C1313EEDFF6D87F1FF637CF0FF4253EBFF3743E9FF4B5DECFF728EF2FF5369
      EFFF3C4DEEF91F223D3F00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000D6B38AFFEACA9FFFDFB784FFD4A568FF4D36
      21800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002040202639D2236
      BBFF2841C7FF101AB8FF03035EA300000107000000000000263D0C14A4F32439
      BFFF131FBCFF080C91D700000612000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000090A
      1010282F6B6D3A47BDC55367EFF95C75F6FF5E77F5FF5A72F3FC4E60D8E02C35
      888C111320200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000D9BA97F8F6DDBDFFEDCEA6FFE2BC8BFF4E39
      2479000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000101
      1E300202355301011F31000000000000000000000000000000000000090E0101
      253B0101263D0000090F00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000937552BEC0986AFFBA9163FFAF8559FA3528
      1A4E000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000000000000000424D3E000000000000003E000000
      2800000040000000200000000100010000000000000100000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000FFFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000}
  end
  object MainMenuOne: TMainMenu
    Images = ImageList1
    Left = 104
    Top = 72
    object Novidades1: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Novidades'
      object Action11: TMenuItem
        Action = Action1
        SubMenuImages = ImageList1
      end
      object Action21: TMenuItem
        Action = Action2
        SubMenuImages = ImageList1
      end
      object Action31: TMenuItem
        Action = Action3
        SubMenuImages = ImageList1
      end
      object Action41: TMenuItem
        Action = Action4
        SubMenuImages = ImageList1
      end
    end
  end
end*
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Add the DFM files as well son that one can test your program.

Comment: nolaspeaker = 
The second image displays the error, the texts are not legible.

Comment: fpiette = Also added the .dfm font.

Comment: Did anyone error get anything about that error?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have seen exactly the same bug.  Please see my question at:

[Vcl Styles issue for menu items added during program load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65390989/vcl-styles-issue-for-menu-items-added-during-program-load/)

The responses indicated that it is known bug in Delphi 10.4 onwards.  A good workround, which I used, is to turn off the vcl styles for the menus, as shown in the accepted answer to my question.

Comment: I generated a test according to the link mentioned above, the result is as expected = Working.
However, this will be a temporary solution until the version 10.4 fix is ​​applied.

Thank you for your time and dedication, thank you very much!